# запустить приложение в ubuntu с заданным разрешением

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

Есть ли возможность задать приложению отдельное разрешение, отличное от разрешения в ноутбуке?

Пример:

Есть ноутбук, на нем, допустим, 1024 х 768
есть Intellij Idea для которой хочу задать 800 х 600

Answer (score 1):

если я правильно понял смысл вопроса, то — нет, отдельной программе — нельзя (не представляю себе, как это вообще возможно, в рамках одного экрана).

но можно запустить программу вместе с новым *x*-сервером, которому в конфигурации можно указать требуемую размерность экрана.

---

демонстрация:

минимальный конфигурационный файл (ключевая строка — `modes "800x600"`):

```
Section "ServerLayout"
  Identifier     "X.org Configured"
  Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier "Screen0"
  SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Depth     24
    Modes "800x600"
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

сохраните его под произвольным именем. например, `800.600.config`.

и запускайте *x*-сервер одновременно с программой. пример запуска программы *xterm*:

```
$ sudo startx xterm -- -config /путь/к/800.600.config
```

*x*-сервер запустится на очередном свободном виртуальном терминале (скорее всего, девятом, а переключиться «обратно» к «основному» *x*-серверу, вероятно, на восьмом в.т., можно комбинацией <kbd>alt+ctrl+f8</kbd>).

при завершении программы *xterm* (с помощью <kbd>ctrl+d</kbd> или `exit`) завершит работу и запущенный *x*-сервер и вы вернётесь к предыдущему виртуальному терминалу (где у вас, вероятно, запущен «основной» *x*-сервер).

Comment: Результат получился не тот который ожидал.  По ссылке картинка https://yadi.sk/i/nWFIduf1qT9Uk

Comment: @fruitjazzy, у меня есть подозрение, что в вопросе вы хотели спросить не про *разрешение*, а про *размер окна*, и просто смешали эти понятия.

Comment: да, вы правы. прошу прощения за ребус

Comment: @fruitjazzy, понятно. вы «вручную» (с помощью «мыши») можете изменить размер окна?

Comment: да, могу. (еще пару символов)

Comment: @fruitjazzy, но после изменения размера окна и перезапуска программы, создавшей окно, окно вновь развёрнуто на весь экран? если да, то какой wm вы используете?