# Запуск графического режима из терминала?

Tags: c++, linux

Я знаю, что в DOS игры запускались напрямую из консоли.
Есть ли возможность запустить графический режим в консоли (которая в линуксе - ttyx) без входа в графическое окружение?
Решение желательно для c++.

Comment: А в windows - нет.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/504659/178576

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer подойдет?

Comment: а мне интересен вариант с gtk..
надо будет посмотреть исходники debian-installer